# Is it possible to vertically align a div which is set to float on the right?

Tags: html, css

Given the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>Midweek Meeting Schedule</title>
<style type="text/css">
/* Column widths */
.columnTime {
    width: 7%;
}

.columnTheme1Class {
    width: 76%;
}

.columnName {
    width: 17%;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

table th, td {
    /* Comment out the following line if you do not want borders */
    border: 1px #d3d3d3 solid;
    /* This is the default font for all cells */
    font-family: Calibri;
}

table tbody tr:hover td {
    color: #000;
    background: #efefef;
}

body{
    width:100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    background: #666;
}

.containerPage {
    min-width: 210mm;
    max-width: 210mm;
    padding-left: 2mm;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #FFF;
}

.containerMeeting {
    margin-bottom: 5mm;
}

.cellTime {
    padding-left: 3mm;
    padding-right: 5mm;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: gray;
}

.cellName {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.floatRight {
    color: gray;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: none;
}

.tableAYFM {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}

.textAYFM {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #c18626;
    width: 90mm;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.bulletAYFM {
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 1mm;
    color: #c18626;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.cellClass {
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    color: gray;
}


.textDuration {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.textTheme {
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

@media print {
    body{
        background: #FFF;
    }

    .containerPage, .containerMeeting, .tableAYFM {
        width: 99%;
        min-width: 99%;
        max-width: 99%;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }

}</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="containerPage">
    <div class="containerMeeting">
        <table class="tableAYFM">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" />
                <col class="columnTheme1Class" />
                <col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:49</td>
                <td>
                <div class="floatRight">
                    Student:<br />
                    Assistant:</div>
                <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Initial 
                Call</span> <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less) 
                <span lang="en-gb">THIS IS EXTRA TEXT.<br />
                I FORCE IT TO HAVE 3 LINES.<br />
                HERE IS THE REST.</span></span></td>
                <td class="cellName">Name 1<br />
                Name 2</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

This is what it looks like (area in question highlighted in yellow):

[image: div alignment issue]

Is it possible to get that div to align vertically, whatever amount of text there is to the left of it? So that it is better aligned with the adjacent cell?

Thank you.

Comment: You could use a little javascript to force it down as much as needed. You'll need the tr's height and the floated div's heigt, substract them, divide by two and put that as top-margin to the yellow div. I'm not sure if you can do this by CSS given the current HTML structure

Comment: Thank you. I don't think I can use javascript in this instance. It is inside a CHtmlView which encompasses a web browser control.

Comment: What about adding an extra td instead of trying to fix it with a div? Isn't it actual tabular data you want to show? For that td you can use vertical-align on the inner text.

Comment: Don't use javascript to perform styling unless you have no other choice. In this particular case, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a column for the "position titles":

```css
/* Column widths */
.columnTime {
    width: 7%;
}

.columnTheme1Class {
    width: 65%;
}

.columnName {
    width: 17%;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

table th, td {
    /* Comment out the following line if you do not want borders */
    border: 1px #d3d3d3 solid;
    /* This is the default font for all cells */
    font-family: Calibri;
}

table tbody tr:hover td {
    color: #000;
    background: #efefef;
}

body{
    width:100%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    background: #666;
}

.containerPage {
    min-width: 210mm;
    max-width: 210mm;
    padding-left: 2mm;
    padding-right: 2mm;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: #FFF;
}

.containerMeeting {
    margin-bottom: 5mm;
}

.cellTime {
    padding-left: 3mm;
    padding-right: 5mm;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: gray;
}

.cellContent {
    border-right: none;
}

.cellPosition {
    padding-right: 5px;
    color: gray;
    text-align: right;
    border-left: none;
}
.cellPosition, .cellName {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.tableAYFM {
    margin-bottom: 2mm;
}

.textAYFM {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #c18626;
    width: 90mm;
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.bulletAYFM {
    padding-top: 1mm;
    padding-bottom: 1mm;
    padding-right: 1mm;
    color: #c18626;
    font-size: 14pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.cellClass {
    font-size: 8pt;
    font-weight: 700;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    color: gray;
}


.textDuration {
    padding-left: 1mm;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 9pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.textTheme {
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: normal;
}

@media print {
    body{
        background: #FFF;
    }

    .containerPage, .containerMeeting, .tableAYFM {
        width: 99%;
        min-width: 99%;
        max-width: 99%;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
    }

}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="containerPage">
    <div class="containerMeeting">
        <table class="tableAYFM">
            <colgroup>
                <col class="columnTime" />
                <col class="columnTheme1Class" />
                <col class="columnX" />
                <col class="columnName" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td class="cellTime">19:49</td>
                <td class="cellContent">
                  <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Initial 
                  Call</span> <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less) 
                  <span lang="en-gb">THIS IS EXTRA TEXT.<br />
                  I FORCE IT TO HAVE 3 LINES.<br />
                  HERE IS THE REST.</span></span>
                </td>
                <td class="cellPosition">
                    Student:<br />
                    Assistant:
                </td>
                <td class="cellName">
                  Name 1<br />
                  Name 2
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't align vertically using a floating element on the right : a floating element is out of the flow, so it cannot "see" the height of the element next to it.

However, you can use two inline-block elements and the CSS property `vertical-align`.

**HTML**

```
<td>
  <div class="left">
    <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span>
    <span class="textTheme">Initial 
    Call</span>
    <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less) 
      <span lang="en-gb">
        THIS IS EXTRA TEXT.<br />
        I FORCE IT TO HAVE 3 LINES.<br />
        HERE IS THE REST.
      </span>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
      Student:<br />
      Assistant:
  </div>
</td>
```

**CSS**

```
.left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 89%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: gray;
  padding-top: 1mm;
  padding-bottom: 1mm;
  padding-right: 2mm;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: none;
}
```

The inconvenient is you have to specify a width <= 100% on the left block (90% on the example). It's the only way I know to align vertically correctly (except flexbox I don't know how to use yet).

The big advantage is that it is a *real* vertical alignement : you can add as much text as you want on the left, it will still work.

[See demo here based on your code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGqKgN)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `<tr>`different:

```
        <tr>
            <td class="cellTime">19:49</td>
            <td>
            <span class="bulletAYFM">•</span> <span class="textTheme">Initial 
            Call</span> <span class="textDuration">(2 min. or less) 
            <span lang="en-gb">THIS IS EXTRA TEXT.<br />
            I FORCE IT TO HAVE 3 LINES.<br />
            HERE IS THE REST.</span></span>
            </td>
            <td valign="middle" style="width: 15%; text-align:right;">
                Student:<br />
                Assistant:
            </td>
            <td class="cellName">Name 1<br />
            Name 2</td>
        </tr>
```

However, is a weird way to make this task.

Comment: Thank you. I aooreciate I could add an extra column, It would make sense I suppose. It would affect the other rows on the table though. But I will give this some thought. Thank you.

Comment: It just fix with `colspan="2"` in the other cells. It's easy. However, I insist is better to make this task with another technique (not tables, not floats)